# What is a hard fork?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork

When people talk about possible changes to how Bitcoin works they sometimes say a particular change would require a hard fork. What does that mean? Can a hard fork cause problems?

Comment: related: [What is a soft fork?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/what-is-a-soft-fork)

Comment: Will Hard fork affect Bitcoin value to decrease?
I mean due to Blockchain split

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply put, a so-called **hard fork** is a change of the Bitcoin protocol that is not backwards-compatible; i.e., older client versions would not accept blocks created by the updated client, considering them invalid. Obviously, this can create a blockchain fork when nodes running the new version create a separate blockchain incompatible with the older software.

For potential future changes that would require a hard fork, see the associated [wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardfork_Wishlist).

Comment: Should 'hard fork' not be constrained to Bitcoin protocol, and strictly define a condition in a blockchain network where node consensus diverges permanently.

Comment: What do you mean? The answer of BinaryMage mentions "is a change of the Bitcoin protocol".

Comment: He meant limiting the definition to Bitcoin is unnecessarily restrictive. Ethereum has had hard forks too, and @BinaryMage's description of what a hard fork is would work equally well there, except for the fact that Ethereum doesn't use the Bitcoin protocol.

Comment: I think you mean HF is not forward-compatible. It *is* BWC in the sense that "the new understands the old" which is the common definition in most dictionaries.