# What Prevents the number of Bitcoins from being increased? After 21 Million?

Tags: blockchain, future-proof, architecture

Can the bitcoin MAX_MONEY attribute simply be changed from 21 Million to a higher number? If not what prevents this from being done?

What would happen to existing addresses and accounts if MAX_MONEY is changed and recompiled?

Comment: The problem is everybody *else* has to agree with your decision.

Comment: Just as in your other question, changing MAX_MONEY would cause a [hard fork](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9173/what-is-a-hardfork).