# What are some essential features of Bitcoin classic?

Tags: block-size-increase, bitcoin-classic

I already know about the 2MB block size increase. I would like to know more about who controls the code base, what the other proposed changes are, and those kinds of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different wishes to what should go into classic, but I strongly believe that they will keep the promise given at https://bitcoinclassic.com/ - to only include the patch allowing for 2 MB blocks (BIP-102, possibly with some tweaking) - otherwise it will be very hard to get the required adoption.

On the longer term (after we have successfully migrated to bigger blocks), there may be other changes coming.  The biggest news with Classic is the governance model.  I haven't paid attention, but they wanted to create a manifest, sort of a "constitution" which will tell how to handle similar conflicts in the future.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://bitcoinclassic.com/ there are no additional patches except the blocksize increase yet.

> It starts as a one-feature patch to bitcoin-core that increases the blocksize limit to 2 MB. We will have ports for master and 0.11.2, so that miners and businesses can upgrade to 2 MB blocks from any recent bitcoin software version they run.

In the times of git, nobody really controls a code base, it is just out there. The essential question is: What version is run/accepted by the majority of nodes (miners, merchants, users, ...).  You should read about [hardforks](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9173/what-is-a-hard-fork) if you haven't.