# Is it a relatively big fee buying Bitcoin on bitcoin.com?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I bought some Bitcoin on Robinhood for $0 fee, and about $2.99 fee on Coinbase.com, but since bitcoin.com seems like an official website, I tried installing the app to buy some Bitcoin, but for $180 of Bitcoin, the fees are like $13.50 + $2.32 = $15.82   (as paid by Apple Pay).

It seems such as big percentage (8.3%) of fees just to buy $180 of Bitcoin.  Is that just the way it is on bitcoin.com or any method to make the fees at most about 3%?

Comment: Bitcoin has no official website, and bitcoin.com isn't anywhere near it.

Comment: bitcoin.com has bitcoin wallet... so if I don't use bitcoin.com, how do I get a Bitcoin wallet? (it seems Coinbase has a wallet app on the App store... Robinhood has an app but I am not sure if it is also a wallet)

Comment: Install one of your own. I like Electrum (electrum.org) personally. Also, I'm confused, it looked like Robinhood fulfilled your question requirements of <3% fee, I haven't tried it myself but why not just keep using it if it worked for you? I also would recommend staying far away from bitcoin.com.

Comment: @ieatpizza because I am just exploring the options and the pros and cons.  Robinhood seems to only buy it in their name and they said they store it "cold" for me. But they don't allow me to transfer to my wallet... unlike Coinbase... so Robinhood is like buying it and selling it only, like a stock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **bitcoin.com seems like an official website**

No, it is in no way official. If I remember correctly it was started by a group of people who created a new cryptocurrency by [forking Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9173/what-is-a-hard-fork), they wanted to take over the name Bitcoin for their [altcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Altcoin). They are not well regarded by the Bitcoin community. Their altcoin is [not Bitcoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_Cash)

There are no officials and no official websites for Bitcoin. This is because Bitcoin is intended to be completely decentralised.

> **Is it a relatively big fee buying Bitcoin on bitcoin.com?**

Your numbers for other currency exchanges suggest that this is the case.

> **Is that just the way it is on bitcoin.com**

Yes, apparently they are a business that charges higher fees than some other businesses.

> **how do I get a Bitcoin wallet?**

A good place to start is https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet but also see
[I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/13866)